# How to start new pages automatically whenever the text string cannot fit on the current page in prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn, prawnto

I am trying to generate a PDF invoice using prawn with header, body and footer. The content of the body may change. I'm using bounding_box to place content in the body. If the content cannot fit on the current page body, it should automatically place the remaining content in body portion of the new page. Please help me with the coding.

Comment: That's the default behavior when using the `text` method. Can you clarify what problems you're running into?

Comment: I am using 
pdf.bounding_box([20, pdf.cursor], :width => 520, :height => 130) do
******body********
end

I am looping this bounding_box for 16 times ,which is generating some new pages,but the position of bounding box is changing,it is not printing at the begining of the new page insted it is going to footer.how should i automatically place the remaining content in starting portion of the new page

i think using pdf.cursor is wrong,please help me.

Comment: Hi, to do this, you can use the `span` method instead of `bounding_box`. The purpose of bounding box is to allow you to select a subregion of the page for rendering stuff into, a `span` allows you to set a desired width and flow to the top of the page on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `span()` method rather than `bounding_box()`. This will allow you to set the width of your text block, but it will reflow to the top of the page when you start a new page.